# How do I make a right aligned text move to new line when switched to mobile view

Tags: html, css, media

I have a div which has two spans which are left and right aligned respectively. On switching to mobile view, the right aligned text should move to next line.

```
<div align="left">
    <span style="float: left;">Receipt No:</span>
    <span style="float: right";>#1111</spa>
</div>
```

when switched to mobile view, #1111 should be under Receipt No: text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your span is not `display: block`.

I assume when that line breaks to the next line, you'll want it left aligned and beneath, not beneath and still right aligned.

I suggest using media queries. I do not suggest trying to use media queries inline, so you'll want to move your CSS into your `<head>`

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
.alignleft {align: left;}
.floatleft {float: left;}
.floatright {float: right;}
@media only screen and (min-resolution: 117dpi) and (max-resolution: 119dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 131dpi) and (max-resolution: 133dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 145dpi) and (max-resolution: 154dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 162dpi) and (max-resolution: 164dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 169dpi) {
    .mobilebreak {display: block; float: left;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alignleft">
<span class="floatleft">Receipt No:</span>
<span class="floatright mobilebreak">#1111</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. I used media queries. Both display: block; float: none and display:block; float:left works. But I guess it is safer to use float: left.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, where 480px is mobile view. You can tweak this to your liking.

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .number {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div align="left">
    <span>Receipt No:</span>
    <span class="number">#1111</spa>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked! Only that I've to remove "display: inline-block". (wonder why) Rest of the code does the job. Thanks.